# How to schedule code for a specific date on a serverless architecture

Tags: aws-lambda, queue, scheduled-tasks, serverless, schedule

I know there are ways to implement cron jobs in a serverless architecture such that a specific code is called at a periodic rate, but I want to schedule different times for different codes.

Idealy I will have a Queue with Events being added and each Event would have a date at which it will be removed from the Queue and sent to a Function. But during a Google search I couldn't find any architectures like this, just periodic, recurring, scheduling, like a "call this every 60 seconds".

Are there any widely adopted architectures like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CloudWatch Event rule for each of the different times. If they are just based on a specific point in time (e.g. January 31st at 1PM) and not recurring (e.g. every day at 2PM), you could have the lambda delete the rule after running.

If the times are vast, and that solution isn't very scalable, you could have the lambda run every minute (or whatever frequency is reasonable for you) and have that lambda read records from a DynamoDB table with the times in it. You can put the time value in the sort key on a GSI and query for records that are in the past and haven't been run yet. After doing your work you update the DynamoDB record so that it doesn't return in future runs.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about those 2 options, but think they are so limited and not scale well, I can't believe there isn't a better way to solve this.

Comment: The DynamoDB one would scale really well, but it takes more work to implement.

Comment: How would it scale if I have 1 lambda to process 100k events in less than 1 minute... Maybe 1 million events? The database will scale, but I would like to scale the lambda units too.

Comment: One lambda could trigger many others, but still, the way the lambdas won't collide should be very reliable, or I will get double executions.

Comment: If you need to process a lot of messages you probably should use one lambda to figure out what needs to be run and put a message in SQS for each message. Then you can have Lambda process the messages from SQS.

Comment: Hmm yeah, this might scale better. But still, the scheduling is not ideal, as I will be wasting Landa processing time on the minutes that I don't have any events to process, which will happen a lot on the middle of the night.

Comment: That's likely going to cost you less than $.10/month.